# Python random choice from list

Tags: python-3.x

How do i choose to pick random choice from the list given below.

```
colours = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple', 'Brown', 'Orange', 'violet', 'gray']
```

1. now pick 1 item from above 10 items list.
2. print
3. pick 2 items from remaining 9 items.
4. print
5. finally pick 3 items from remaining 7 items.
6. print
7. So final result will be like this

Brown

green and violet

red black and gray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would just be to delete the chosen values from the list. It is slightly simpler if you use `set`s:

```
In []:
colours = {'red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple',
           'Brown', 'Orange', 'violet', 'gray'}
for n in [1, 2, 3]:
    cs = random.sample(colours, k=n)
    colours -= set(cs)
    print(cs)

Out[]:
['Brown']
['Orange', 'red']
['purple', 'gray', 'blue']
```

Comment: @Demotry what you ask in your comment is obviosly another question!  Please judge the (good) answers you have received  with respect to the question you actually asked and move on to ask another question for your  "discordation" problem

Comment: yes but if i create another question it to work that in discord does it refers to duplicate question ?

Answer (score 0):

The method I use consist in shuffling your input vector take the selected number of elements you need.

```
import random

colours = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple', 'Brown', 'Orange', 'violet', 'gray']
random.shuffle(colours)

for i in range(1, 4):
  n, colours = colours[0:i], colours[i:]
  print(n)
```

Comment: No need to re-shuffle each time. Shuffle **once**.

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple','Brown', 'Orange', 'violet', 'gray']
for n in range(1,4):
    select=np.random.choice(colors,n)
    print(select)
    colors=list(set(colors).difference(set(select)))

output:-['Brown']
        ['red' 'violet']
        ['yellow' 'Orange' 'black']
```

Comment: @Demotry i am beginner,I dont have any idea about your question.

Comment: Its ok. I got answer from Tristo.